# Validation messages not showing when return to ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal form where a user can input a new dog. The form is posted via $.ajax call to the controller and when the model.isvalid() = true it saves the dog to the database and closes the modal form. That is working fine. The problem is when the model.isvalid() != true. I can get the errormessages to show up.

The modal form :

```
<div class="modal fade modal-dialog-center col-md-12" tabindex="0" role="dialog" id="modalAddHond" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog ">
        <div class="modal-content-wrap">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-title">
                    <h4>Nieuwe hond toevoegen of bewerken</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id="addHondContainer"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    press esc or <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Close</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" id="saveandclosehond">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is part of an overview page. On that page I have a button that calls following script:

```
addhondmodal: function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Honden/AddNewHond",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.success) {
                    $("#modalAddHond .modal-body").html(data.html);
                    $("#modalAddHond").modal();
                }
                else {
                    alert("No modal form");
                }
            }
        });
}
```

This opens the Modal Form and does some initializing like building the dropdownlists. The modal form is:

```
@model HtbGpWebApp.Models.Honden.HondenModel

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/js")
@Scripts.Render("~/assets/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/assets/addhondjs")

@section PageScripts {
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
}

<form id="addhondform" method="Post" class="container">
    <div class="col-md-pull-8">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
    <div class="row padding-top-10">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Naam)
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Naam, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Naam, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row padding-top-10">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RoepNaam)
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RoepNaam, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RoepNaam, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GeboorteDatum)
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="input-group date" data-provider="datepicker" id="GeboorteDatum">
                @if (Model.GeboorteDatum == DateTime.MinValue)
                {
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.GeboorteDatum, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control", @Value = "" })
                }
                else
                {
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.GeboorteDatum, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                }
                <div class="input-group-addon" id="buttonGeboorteDatum">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row padding-top-10">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Kennel)
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Kennel, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Kennel, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GeslachtId)
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div id="geslachtendropdown"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row padding-top-10">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RasId)
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div id="rassendropdown"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GeleiderId)
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div id="geleidersdropdown"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row padding-top-10">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ChipNummer)
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ChipNummer, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Stamboom)
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Stamboom, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row padding-top-10">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SpeeltVoorClubId)
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div id="clubsdropdown"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

note: this is a part of the modal form, there are some additional textboxes and drop downs which.

The script when a user pushes the 'save' button is like this:

```
savenewhond: function () {
        var data = $("#addhondform").serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: window.framework.fqurl(window.constants.url.honden.savehond),
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.success) {
                    $("#modalAddHond").modal("hide");
                    window.overzichthonden.overzicht.inittable();
                }
                else {
                    //window.overzichthonden.overzicht.addhondmodal(data.returnmodel);
                    $("#addhondform").html(data.html);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

The controller/method that is called in this ajax-call looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SaveHond(HondenModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                IHondenRepository hondenRepo = new HondenRepository();

                Hond hond = new Hond()
                {
                    ChipNummer = model.ChipNummer,
                    GeboorteDatum = model.GeboorteDatum,
                    GeleiderId = model.GeleiderId,
                    GeslachtId = model.GeslachtId,
                    Kennel = model.Kennel,
                    Naam = model.Naam,
                    RasId = model.RasId,
                    RoepNaam = model.RoepNaam,
                    SpeeltVoorClubId = model.SpeeltVoorClubId,
                    StamBoom = model.Stamboom
                };

                var hondId = hondenRepo.Create(hond);
                return Json(new { success = true, selectedid = hondId });
            }
            else
            {
                //var html = RenderPartialViewToString("Honden/AddNewHond", model);
                //return Json(new { success = false, html, returnmodel = model });
                return PartialView("Honden/AddNewHond", model);
            }
        }
```

I've already tried some answers in other posts like this but I don't seem to get it right.

Where am I going wrong? Am I missing something?

Kind regards
Peter

Comment: The model behind this has some dataannotations like: Required(ErrorMessage ="Naam van de hond is verplicht")]
        public string Naam { get; set; }

Comment: is the return type from your web service JSON ?

Comment: @EdisonTrutwein: when success, it is indeed a JSON type, otherwise it gives back the partial view. I found this in another post because my modal form initializes when I returen Json (the code for that is in comment in the else part of the controller/method)

Comment: could you try specifying the dataType in the ajax call as json dataType:"json"

Comment: I tried this, it works only for the input-fields but not the dropdowns (but that I can manage I think). But the problem is that I now have 2 forms with the same name. Therefor if I repost the model is empty (because I use .Serialize() in the Jquery and it is confused which selector I want to serialize.

Comment: I guess, either you should have different names for the form or else you could relate which form to submit based on the form submission button by looking up the form element using "this"

Answer (score 0):

I found out there were 2 problems: the naming of the form and elements (which needed to be unique) and second I didn't include the jquery library jqueryval. When I added this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/assets/jqueryval")
```

at the top of the modal form, all works fine.